# how do I find proportion of the total respondents were aged less than 45 in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

how do I find the proportion of the total respondents who were aged less than 45 in pandas?

I have tried this code till now

```
survey['age_45']=(survey['age'] < 45)
survey['result']=(survey['age_45']  / survey ['age'].count())*100
survey['result']
```

Comment: If you want just the number (between 0-1), do: `proportion = len(survey[survey['age'] < 45]) / len(survey)`.

Answer (score 1):

the `len()` function will allow you to count the elements in a dataframe. in the code below, proportion = 0.4

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Person":
                   ["John", "Myla", "Lewis", "John", "Myla"],
                   "Age": [55, 60, 45, 40, 28] })

proportion = len(df[df['Age']<45]) / len(df)
```